# Modify all links in html to keep hashtag only

Tags: php, regex

In html file I have links like

`<a href="index_split_037.xhtml#id145937_n22">`.

How do I modify them all so after the process it becomes

`<a href="#id145937_n22">`.

Basically, I need to keep hashtag only.

Comment: links like? afterwords it becomes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [`ob_start`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ob-start.php) to capture the output and [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) to change the `href` attribute:

```
<?php

ob_start(); // Capture the output

?>

<!--- Links --->
<a href="index_split_037.xhtml#id145937">Link 1</a>
<a href="index_split_038.xhtml#id147_n22">Link 2</a>
<a href="index_split_039.xhtml#id_n22">Link 3</a>
<a href="index_split_040.xhtml#145937_n22">Link 4</a>

<?php

$output = ob_get_contents(); // Get the output
ob_end_clean(); // Finish capture

// Remove the letters in href attribute before the hash # maintaining the others attributes
echo preg_replace('/<a(.*)href="([^"#]*)#([^"]*)"(.*)>/','<a$1href="#$3"$4>', $output);

?>
```

See the regexp: http://regexr.com/39bmb.
See how works the example: [SandBox example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cd33d8c25e0f9a96672d82bcc65e0cb71ed1d4c4).

Comment: Thanks, Snake. You have the most complete RegEx rule for the replacement. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
(<a href=")[^#]*([^>]*>)
```

Replacement string:

```
\1\2
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kF7hL3/1)

Example:

```
<?php
$mystring = "The input string foo <a href=\"index_split_037.xhtml#id145937_n22\"> bar";
echo preg_replace('~(<a href=")[^#]*([^>]*>)~', '\1\2', $mystring);
?>
```

Output:

```
The input string foo <a href="#id145937_n22"> bar
```

**Explanation:**

- `(<a href=")` The string `<a href="` was captured by group 1.
- `[^#]*` Matches any character not of `#` zero or more times.  Once the symbol `#` was found, regex engine stops the matching operation.
- `([^>]*>)` Again the following characters upto the next `>` symbol are captured by group 2.
- In the replacement part, we are replacing the matched characters with the characters inside the captured groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
 (.*?")(?:.*?)(#.*)
```

See demo .

http://regex101.com/r/yM7jY2/1